# Spring boot on Aws ec2 instance

Tags: java, spring, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

[Spring boot demo app](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tried on localhost and successfully run the application. I even installed

> gradle,jdk and other dependencies

easily on aws instance . Even though i ran `./gradlew bootRun` of sample application successfully .

Like http:// localhost:8080 aws instane isn't working according to my path like http://myip:8080.

Let me know what exactly i am doing wrong with this and also to make sure i added custom tcp rule such as 8080 .

Comment: It works on localhost and not when you use the IP? Can you provide more details please? The IP is an elastic IP? The port must also be unblocked from the AWS management console, has this been done?

Comment: @AlexandruMarina i am not sure about elastic ip but i am trying on public ip to work . No idea about unblocking from aws console!

Comment: @NightOwl did it work for you? I am facing the same problem. No error logs could be found during deployment

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding custom tcp rule 8080, try to add the following rule into your security group.

Type: Custom ICMP Rule
Protocol: Echo Request
Port Range: N/A
Source: 0.0.0.0/0

And then try to ping YourIP in order to see if your EC2 machine can be reach from internet. If your EC2 ip is pingable, then I guess the reason why you cannot access http://myip:8080 is your spring boot failed to start in EC2.

You can [ssh into your ec2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) and investigate your jar. I don't know any clever method but my method is:
After ssh into the ec2 machine,

1. Find your jar name by `ps -A -F` . In my case I can find `java -jar application.jar`
2. Find your jar path by `sudo find / -name application.jar` . In my case I can find `/var/app/current/application.jar`
3. Then you can `cd /var/app/current/` and `java -jar application.jar` . If you are lucky, you can find some hints from the spring boot log.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this call to work there are a couple of prerequisites.I will try to make a short list, other things could arise depending on the environment.

1. Make sure the public IP address is the same as the one you know. This changes after each reboot. If you do not want this behavior you can use an elastic IP
2. The 8080 port is accessible from the Internet. Here are some steps to make sure this is the case: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: I already done with this change setting custom tcp rule as 8080 port but it didnt work out.